# stretch canvas on maximize

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

(Can't add pictures so I'll try and explain it) So my program basically consists of two parts: a bitmap image that is scanned and shown in the main window (on a canvas), and a canvas derived class I made that basically takes data (b&w values ranging from 0-255) from the image and represents it in a histogram format (a bargraph basically) and it overlays the bitmap image (its transparent so you can still see the image).

Alright so I got my program working, the only problem is my canvas derived class wont stretch until I "refresh" the screen. The children of the class (being windows shapes rectangles) wont stretch with the window.

It looks fine up to this point

but then I maximize it...

The rectangles then just stay exactly where they're at. It isn't until I click the "display histogram" button that it will disappear and then after clicking it again, I get...

...Exactly what I want, the histogram is in the right place on the screen. So here's my question, how can I get the histogram to stretch with the main window? instead of having to refresh it every time?

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5" x:Name="testview">
        <local:DrawingCanvas x:Name="pbHistogram" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                Width="Auto"
                Background="Transparent"
                Height ="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=testview}"/>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, have you tried calling InvalidateVisual and/or InvalidateMeasure when maximized?

Comment: Can't Say I have, How exactly would I go about that?

Comment: Actually, just tried it; neither work. It disables my display histogram button and slows down my program noticeably, thanks for the help though!

Comment: @MrBretten Have you tried triggering your height change on the SizeChanged event when your window changes size? And how is ActualHeight being bound? Do you have the ViewModel implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: I'm new, so how do I vote this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is not really an answer, but I think the problem is the canvas class itself. It has no automatic layouting or resizing of its child elements. Link to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms609101(v=vs.100).aspx

What you could try is to hook up to your main window's resize event and call the same function that the buttonpress calls.

Comment: It's not the canvas class, again I made a made a class that derived from Canvas. That way I could get an auto layout and re-size the child elements

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the quickest, easiest way to do this would be to put your canvas in a Viewbox.